# How can I create a combobox in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, combobox

I m using MVC4. I need a combobox which will allow a user to input a new value if it does not exist, or which will automatically be selected if it exists among the available values. 
How can I achieve this ?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(model) model.XYZ.Id, 
                      New SelectList(Model.XYZ, 
                                     "ID", 
                                     "Name", 
                                     Model.XYZList.First().Id))
```

This will generate a dropdownlist , but it won't allow users to type a new entry.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML does not have combobox like in windows forms. You should try javascript. Check out jquery autocomplete.

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: The link you provided is 404.

Comment: @İbrahimULUDAĞ Next time just fix the broken link in the answer.

Comment: The link is working. Also may someone find helpful to read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21822731/jquery-ui-autocomplete-combobox-changed-not-firing and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41582627/jquery-combobox-autocomplete