# Jquery how to receive value from input field without name and id

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, input

I have a nice script from https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Bootstrap-Combo-Box-Typeahead-Plugin-jQuery.html to convert a select with options to a `combobox`, but also able to see all options as in a select.

But the problem is that it returns the option in an input field without id and name. No event is working for me and I need its selected value for other jquery statements.

Maybe the creator will answer some day, maybe he/she does not look to questions anymore (I am the first but the script have been visited 12000 times until now).

Is there a way for an input field without id and name ?

This is an example of the generated `html` from a select (it is the input field with the `autocomplete="off"`):

```
<div class="col-sm-12"> 
  <span>A6. Geslacht</span>
  <div class="combobox-container"> 
    <input name="A06" value="" type="hidden"> 
    <div class="input-group"> 
      <input autocomplete="off" placeholder="" class="combobox form-control" style="" type="text">
      <ul class="typeahead typeahead-long dropdown-menu" style="top: 40px; left: 0px; display: none;">
        <li data-value="M" class="active"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><strong></strong>M<strong></strong></a></li>
        <li data-value="V"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item"><strong></strong>V<strong></strong></a></li>
      </ul>
      <span class="input-group-addon dropdown-toggle" data-dropdown="dropdown">
        <span class="caret"></span> 
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
      </span> 
    </div> 
  </div>
  <select id="input-A06" class="combobox form-control" style="display: none;">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">M</option>
    <option value="2">V</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not by class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*«No event is working for me»* Really? Have you tryed `change`?

*«I need its selected value»* That sounds clear... But there is the `value`, the `text` and the `selectedIndex` that exist... So look below for what you really need.

```js
$(".combobox").combobox().on("change",function(){
  var value = this.value;
  var index = this.selectedIndex;
  var text = $(this).find("option").eq(index).text();
  
  console.log(value);
  console.log(index);
  console.log(text);
});;
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-combobox/1.1.8/css/bootstrap-combobox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-combobox/1.1.8/js/bootstrap-combobox.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-12"> 
  <span>A6. Geslacht</span>
  
  <select id="input-A06" class="combobox form-control" style="display: none;">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">M</option>
    <option value="2">V</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I just found the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667882/jquery-combobox-onchange-event-in-bootstrap-not-working from 2014 and worked. But the problem when you enter text the event works again, but with this nice example (code snippet) it returns a 0 and so usable for me. Thanks all for the very fast answers and the nice tool of code snippet, but this was the best for me. Thank you very much Louys!

Comment: With a dummy class name I can give it an unique name (I have many selects).

Comment: Can you read the jQuery docs next time? If you did, you would know there is a [better way to do this.](https://api.jquery.com/change/).

Comment: I forgot to give +1 for my accepted answer but is not visible for me as a starter .. @Will I know (partly) but it has to be taken over by the generated combobox, I am not that experienced I can change such excellent code easily ..

Comment: No problem about the upvote, pal... The key issue here, was to bind the `change` event on the result produced by `combobox()` which is additionnal markup added to DOM. So the "chaining" does that. What Will Hoskings mentions only is about to replace `.on("change", function(){` by `.change(function(){` which is the "shorthand" of the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it by using class selector.

To be exact (If you're using jQuery):

```
$("input.combobox.form-control").val()
```

Refer here for class referencing:
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_class.asp

Comment: He said he was using jQuery in the question, bud :P