# jQuery Autocomplete Combobox doesn't have a mouse out / tab out event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, combobox, autocomplete

Here is the link that solved one issue: [Jquery ui Autocomplete Combobox - changed not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21822731/jquery-ui-autocomplete-combobox-changed-not-firing#new-answer)

That works great, thanks to Drixson Osena for that answer.

Does this UI control have a similar mouse-out or tab-out event?  We can get by with its existing functionality if it doesn't but it would enhance our app if it does.

Here is the existing code:

```
//district
    $('#project-locationSearch-dist').combobox({
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var districtVal = $('#project-locationSearch-dist').val();
            var returnedSFN = $('#project-locationSearch').val();
            GetSPNsByDistrict(districtVal);
            GetPIDsByDistrict(districtVal);
        }
    });
```

Works great now that we have select: working.  The last 2 function calls populate 2 other jQuery Autocomplete controls.  For those, when users enter in a known value in either and tabs/mouses out we need to fire another event.

Because the search event is always going to be fired, the idea is why use a Search button?  On select or tab/mouse out, just fire the event that way.

Thanks.

Comment: No, you will want to use the native `blur` or `hoverout` events for the element.

Comment: Thanks for looking Twisty.  Just tried blur and hover, neither fired.

Looked up the jQuery methods, nothing seems to work.  mouseout, mouseenter, mouseleave, hover, etc.  They don't fire.

We've decided just to do with the Search button since users will expect to see one anyhow.

Comment: They did not fire at all? Might be helpful to have a more complete example or fiddle to work from.

Comment: one sec ... didn't realize you were right here.  BRB

Comment: `$('#project-locationSearch-dist').on("blur mouseleave", function(e){ console.log(e) });` would be another method. Or use `.blur()` or `.hover()` in the same way.

Comment: There is also a `.mouseleave( handlerOut )` that could be used.

Comment: Wow, not working.  Other methods for the jQuery autocomplete do work.  The example I found was:
spnDDL.blur(function(){ // do some code ... });
Just tried yours, no joy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137952/discussion-between-user1585204-and-twisty).