# Jquery combobox autocomplete

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, combobox, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Need some help.

Can I set the custom value to the combobox, the value which is not present in the list.

It means like my own value which is not listed in the list

Here is the code.

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.widget( "ui.combobox", {
      _create: function() {
        this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
          .insertAfter( this.element )
          .attr('id', this.element[0].id+"_combobox");

        this.element.hide();
        this._createAutocomplete();
        this._createShowAllButton();
      },

      _createAutocomplete: function() {

          var selected = this.element.children(":selected");
          this.input = $( "<input>" )
            .appendTo( this.wrapper )
            .attr( "title", '<fmt:message key="page.claim.personalclaimnotification.injury.select_info" />' )
            .val(selected.text())
            .css({
                color: function( index, value ) {
                    if (this.value == '<fmt:message key="page.claim.search.object.name" />') {
                        return "#777";
                    }
                },
                fontStyle: function( index, value ) {
                    if (this.value == '<fmt:message key="page.claim.search.object.name" />') {
                        return "italic";
                    }
                },
                width: "286px"
            })
            .attr("maxlength", 256)
            .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
            .autocomplete({
              delay: 0,
              minLength: 3,
              source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
            })

          // executes when user selects illness from list
          this._on( this.input, {
            autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
              ui.item.option.selected = true;
              this._trigger( "select", event, {
                item: ui.item.option
              });
            },
            autocompletechange: "_addIfInvalid"

          });

         },   /* _createAutocomplete close */

          _createShowAllButton: function() {
          var input = this.input,
            wasOpen = false;

          $( "<a>" )
            .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
            .appendTo( this.wrapper )
            .attr( "title", '<fmt:message key="page.claim.personalclaimnotification.injury.select_info" />' )
            .button({
              icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
              },
              text: false
            })
            .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
            .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
            .mousedown(function() {
              wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
            })
            .click(function() {

              // Close if already visible
              if ( wasOpen ) {
                return;
              }

              // Pass triple spaces as value to search for, displaying all results (each has triple spaces at the end)
              input.autocomplete( "search", "   " );
            });
        },      /* _createShowAllButton close */

        _source: function( request, response ) {

          var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
          response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
            var text = $( this ).text();
            if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
              return {
                label: text,
                value: text,
                option: this
              };
          }) );
        },


        _addIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {

            // Selected an item, nothing to do
            if ( ui.item ) {
              return;
            }
            // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
            var value = this.input.val(),
              valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
              valid = false;

            this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
              if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
                this.selected = valid = true;
                return false;
              }
            });


            // Found a match, nothing to do
            if ( valid ) {
              return;
            }

            alert("value "+ value +" this.element "+ this.element[0].id );

            // Remove invalid value
            this.input
              .val(value)
              .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
              .tooltip( "open" );
            //this.element.val(value);
            //this.input.val(value);
            $('select').val(value);

            this._delay(function() {
              this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
            }, 2500 );
            this.input.autocomplete( "instance" ).term = "";
          },

        _destroy: function() {
          this.wrapper.remove();
          this.element.show();
        }

        });     /* widget close */
    })( jQuery );   /* function close */ 


$(function() {
    $( ".objectComboBox" ).combobox();

});
```

If the element is not listed in the drop down, that user entered element should be taken as the value and should stay in the combobox field.

Adding the field

Comment: paste some code

Comment: can you explain more? do yo want to add values to the combo box or auto   complete list ?

Comment: Yes. sure :)  @danish

Comment: @ prasad,  If the value is not listed, the user entered value should be taken as the value and should be stay in the combo box field. Is it possible?

Comment: @danish  need help

Comment: let me check bro.

Comment: $( ".objectComboBox" ).combobox(); You are calling your combobox plugin. Show html of this '.objectComboBox' class

Comment: @danish, you are talking about below one.

<div class="ui-widget">
               <html:select  property="dummyObject" styleId="claimObjectCombo" styleClass="objectComboBox" onkeypress="enterStopper(event);">
                    <ykyalli:optionsCollection property="objectTypes"  sort="true"  chooseKey="000" chooseResourceKey="page.claim.search.object.name"/>
               </html:select>
         </div>

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RDd3A/505/ have you this plugin for your selectbox?

Comment: @danish, Yes. I am able to select the values and do autocomplete. For me autocomplete is also working fine.  

I just wanted to know that for any combobox, can we set the value to the combobox field if the user entered value is not found in the list. I just want to set the value and stay in the field which is not found in the list. Is it possible?

Comment: you want to add your own value if it's not in the list. It should be added in list. is that what you want?

Comment: @danish, Yes. I want to add my own value. Is that not possible without adding to the list?

If it should be added, can you tell me how to add it to the list. How to add it in the autocomplete change function. What would be value and text?

Answer (score 0):

I made a script for you. May be it will work for you.

```
  <select  id="combobox" >
    <option>abc</option>
    <option>deg</option>
    <option>gcc</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" id="addfieldtoddl" /><input type="button" value="add" id="add" onclick="addfieldtoddl()" />

  <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#combobox").combobox();
      });
      function addfieldtoddl() {
          var YourValue = $("#addfieldtoddl").val();
          $('#combobox').append('<option val="'+ YourValue +'">'+ YourValue +'</option>');
          $("#combobox").combobox();
      }
  </script>
```

here is fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/RDd3A/506/

Trying to help...!!!

Comment: @disnesh,   Thanks!!  Will check it and let you know.